# gcov with universal binaries

Tags: macos, gcc, gcov

I'm trying to get some code-coverage statistics on a project that builds universal binaries.  However, the .gcno files don't seem to get generated.

An example:

```
$ls
helloworld.c
$cat helloworld.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  printf("hello world \n");
  return 0;
}

$gcc helloworld.c -c -arch x86_64 -arch i386 --coverage
$ls
helloworld.c    helloworld.o
```

But compiling without multiple arches works:

```
$gcc helloworld.c -c -arch x86_64 --coverage
$ls
helloworld.c    helloworld.gcno helloworld.o
$
```

Can anyone shed some light on why this won't work with fat binaries?  Is it documented anywhere?  Workarounds?

Answer (score -1):

try using: `/usr/bin/gcc helloworld.c -c -arch x86_64 -arch i386 --coverage`